# Android webview set width not taken more than screen width

Tags: android, webview, bitmap

I have a web view with match parent layout_width and layout_height, i need to draw the webview into bitmap image and print the image.
The point is the width of the webview is not taken programmatically, i try to change it like this

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    600, 600);
            params.height = paymentp.getAmount().size() * 80 + 180 + 500;// 180
                                                                            // header
                                                                            // w
                                                                            // majmou3,500
                                                                            // for
                                                                            // title
            params.width = 600;
            wvReport.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            wvReport.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            wvReport.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            wvReport.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            wvReport.setLayoutParams(params);
```

but when i create the bitmap with this webview using getHeight and width, the width is taken the screen size (480) always, not taken more.
i need to make the webview width more than screen width

here how i create the bitmap using webview

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    WebView[0].getWidth() ,
                    WebView[0].getHeight() , Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            WebView[0].draw(canvas);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take height and width of webview like below code

```
webview.measure(0,0);
height = webview.getMeasuredHeight();
width  = webview.getMeasuredWidth();
```